# Python Fabric won't comment beginning of line

Tags: python, regex, comments, stdout, fabric

Just trying to comment out a line in a text file in python fabric. Regex is for any @ sign that doesn't have ip1 or ip2 following. The pattern searches just fine and finds the line, except instead of printing "# + line" it prints "#@#@bad_Ip_here". So it should be :

```
#*.info;mail.none;stuff.none;cron.none                @bad_ip
```

but it prints

```
*.info;mail.none;stuff.none;cron.none                #@#@bad_ip
```

It was just printing the commented line twice, which is fine. I don't know what is wrong or what changed. I tried forcing it to insert at position 0 with

```
line = line[:0] + "#" + line[0:]
```

but that didn't work either.

```
def addcomments():
    ip1 = '10.31.xx.xxx'
    ip2 = '10.30.xx.xx'
    host = env.host_string
    conf = open('/home/myuser/verify_yslog_conf/%s/hi.txt' % host, 'r')
    f = conf.read()
    conf.close()
    comment = open('/home/myuser/verify_yslog_conf/%s/hi.txt' % host, 'w')
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'(@(?!({0}|{1})))'.format(ip1, ip2), line):
            line = "#" + line
            comment.write(line) 
        comment.write(line)
    comment.close()
```

thanks

Comment: Did you know that Fabric itself has such a function? ``fabric.contrib.files.comment``

Comment: I would be careful writing to the same file, if you code errors or your application crashed after you open the file for writing your file content would be wiped

Comment: Not a python guru but search should not modify the line. `line = "#" + line` is probably working. Have you tried to print that to the console by itself ?

Comment: @JamesMills ... I do know about that function, but every time I've tried to use it, in any context, it errors out. I get a `sed: -e expression #1, char 26: Invalid preceding regular expression` error or something similar. I get an error every time, and I think it's the regex it doesn't like.